# Does Google App Engine recognize and use a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine Launcher to test my application locally on `localhost:8080`.  I guess that the Google App Engine Launcher uses Python to run a server locally, but I've read that `.htaccess` is an Apache thing.  The example code I'm trying to get to work uses a `.htaccess` file.  I'm trying to figure out if it's a problem with the `.htaccess` file, or something else.  Will Google App Engine recognize and use a `.htaccess` file?

I'm using the Dr Edit PHP example from Git Hub as my code:

[Dr Edit code example](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/php)

This is the code that Google specifically points to as a more complete example of using PHP on Google App Engine.  The repository on Git Hub includes a `.htaccess` file, but does NOT include an `app.yaml` file.  The Google Developers documentation specifically indicates that an `app.yaml` file is needed to configure the application, but then the example code they officially point to leaves out an `app.yaml` file and provides a `.htaccess` file.  I don't understand.

After spending massive amounts of time on this, and seeing how outdated, and outright wrong the documentation from Google is, I don't know if the Dr Edit example can be made to run "As Is" from Git Hub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some code samples would be helpful. But from what I understand of Google App Engine, .htaccess is not directly supported and instead it uses the app.yaml file to accomplish much of what .htaccess provides.

You might find the following links helpful for getting started
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld (assuming your working with PHP)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I added some more info to the original post about what code I'm using.

Comment: The Dr Edit PHP Example is an example app using the Google Drive SDK. As a PHP example, it will run as expected on a typical Apache/PHP web server. To use this example on Google App Engine, you will need to convert your .htaccess rules and add them to the app.yaml file as file or url handlers. The bottom line is that the .htaccess files will not work on GAE. Also keep in mind that the PHP runtime on Google App Engine is still experimental, and support could change at any time.

Comment: I asked a question about how to convert the .htaccess rules to an app.yaml file here:   [Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226114/what-does-the-rewriterule-in-htaccess-convert-to-in-an-app-yaml-file)

Comment: Here's information about how to simulate Apache mod_rewrite $_GET['q'] routing for a PHP App Engine app: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite