# What does the RewriteRule in .htaccess convert to in an app.yaml file?

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine, app.yaml

How do I convert this `.htaccess` file to an `app.yaml` file?

Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?public).* index.php [QSA,L]
```

I need to do this to run an app using PHP on Google App Engine.

The reason I'm asking this question, is because Google specifically recommends a code example in their official documentation that is stored in Git Hub called Dr Edit.  The Dr Edit code example has a `.htaccess` file, but no `app.yaml` file.  And, in the `READ ME` file, the **very first step** for setting up the application, is to **create a Google App Engine application**.  So I guess Google has provided a code example that insinuates it will run on Google App Engine, but it won't.

Supposedly Google is monitoring Stack Overflow for issues related to GAE, so I hope they read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is information about how to [simulate Apache mod_rewrite $_GET['q'] routing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite) for a PHP App Engine app, in case that's helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As the name `.htaccess` implies, it can control access to a directory.  The `.htaccess` files are read on every request.  I guess that means that every HTTP request to the domain name must go through the `.htaccess` file.  So it seems like the `.htaccess` file is like a `gatekeeper`.  From Wikipedia, it seems that the `.htaccess` file can be used to block certain IP address from loading a web page.

The first line of the `.htaccess` file is:  `RewriteEngine On`

That line of code: `RewriteEngine` is an Apache Directive which turns the Apache `Rewriting Engine` on or off.

So that `.htaccess` file is looking at every request, taking the request, then pushing out a different request.

It seems that the `app.yaml` file can not directly take one URL request, and push out a different request, BUT the `app.yaml` file can take a URL request, and then run a PHP script, that will change the request.

So, in the `app.yaml` file, the section that takes the URL, then redirects to a script, would look like this:

Catch the incoming URL requests and cause the `mod_rewrite.php` file to run.

```
- url: /Put the incoming URL you want to monitor, catch and redirect here
  script: mod_rewrite.php
```

[Redirect URL requests with app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite#Example_app)

The second line of the `.htaccess` file is:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

This is a test, looking for a match in the incoming URL request.  The `-f` at the end is for:

> -f (is regular file) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.

Oh wait!  There is an exclamation point in front of it.  That's probably a test for logical not.  So, if it's NOT a regular file?

Whatever that means.  What is the difference between a regular file and everything else?  What's an irregular file?  lol  idk.   Anyway, it's looking for a file I guess.

From the Apache documentation, here is a quote:

> Server-Variables: These are variables of the form %{ NAME_OF_VARIABLE
>   } where NAME_OF_VARIABLE can be a string taken from the following
>   list:

So that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` part of the second line is what Apache is calling a `Server-Variable`, and the specific `Server-Variable` is `REQUEST_FILENAME`.

Here is a quote from the Apache documentation:

> REQUEST_FILENAME
>       The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time
>   REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in
>   virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI. Depending on the
>   value of AcceptPathInfo, the server may have only used some leading
>   components of the REQUEST_URI to map the request to a file.

So I guess the `.htaccess` file is looking for something that looks like a path to files on your local computer?

Finally there is the `Rewrite Rule`  [Apache RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

What is the `QSA` at the end for?  I guess it's called a flag, and:

> Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined

QSA seems to stand for `Query String Append`.  If the incoming URL has a query string on the end of it, how do you want it dealt with?

The [L] prevents any further rewriting rules to be appended

[Appache L rewrite flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)
[Appache Documentation QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

The character (^) is called a caret.  I don't know why it's used at the beginning.  The syntax for the Appache Rewrite directive is:

`RewriteRule pattern target [Flag1,Flag2,Flag3]`

So the caret is part of the pattern being detected.  That target is simply `index.php`.  So it looks like if lots of different possible requests simply get routed back to the `index.php` file, which is the very first thing the application runs.

The asterisk at the end is probably a wildcard for any extension.

Comment: Did this answer help?  I thought that .htaccess was merely a data file, so it cannot do anything, and Apache web server, which does things specified in .htaccess, is not running on AppEngine.  Does Apache the web server actually run your PHP app?  The only two mentions of Apache in [PHP Runtime Environment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/) don't confirm that it does.  The previously mentioned [PHP mod_rewrite simulator](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite) does not use .htaccess.  Out of curiosity, how did you solve your problem?

Comment: I gave up on trying to get the `Dr Edit` example to run.  I am still using GAE, and I did stick to using PHP, but as far as this particular issue goes, it was just another dead end road to nowhere, and a battle I couldn't win I guess.  The good thing about being too stupid to figure out a solution to the problem, is that it forces me to find an easier, simpler way to do it.  lol

Comment: :-) I also find that trying to solve problems is a good way to learn, even if the original problem does not get solved.  Some call it [Yak Shaving](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YakShavingDefinedIllGetThatDoneAsSoonAsIShaveThisYak.aspx) as one example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck :-(  Rewrite is an Apache module but AppEngine is based on [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/), so you must redesign for that.  You might be able to use one of the [Bundled Servlets, Filters, and Handlers](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-extras.html) but none of them are a direct substitute for [Apache Module mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  Some people have used Apache as a front end before Jetty, but that is a clumsy approach. Sorry.

Comment: Looks like there is a way to redirect the URL.

Comment: That's a nifty PHP workaround.  I hope it works for you.