# How to leverage browser caching in a java based maven project on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, browser-cache

Been trying to score 100/100 on Google's [page insights tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), but no matter what i try it won't recognize the .htaccess file (to leverage browser caching for images/font files). The file is currently in the root directory and just copied the .htaccess file from [this boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/edit/master/dist/.htaccess).

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224764/does-google-app-engine-recognize-and-use-a-htaccess-file) has an answer which states:

> .htaccess is not directly supported and instead it uses the app.yaml
>   file to accomplish much of what .htaccess provides.

So how exactly do we go about leveraging browser caching in a java based maven project? (which doesn't use app.yaml)

I can't find any documentation about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a cache duration for specific static file handlers in the appengine-web.xml file, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_cache_expiration). For example:

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/**.png" expiration="4d 5h" />
</static-files>
```

Or you handler can set cache durations by returning the appropriate `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers to the browser.

Comment: Glad I could help :)