# Angular 6 routes not found on Google App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I deployed an Angular 6 application on Google App Engine. The app.yaml config looks like that:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- (?!^dist)

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

Everything works fine and I can access everything till I reload the page on a route or directly access the website by a route (eg. myapp.com/route). Doing that I get a `The requested URL /route was not found on this server` error message.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled and deployed Angular applications contain of a single `index.html` along with a couple of assets, such as JavaScript files. The index file contains all JavaScript files. Routing is performed *virtually* based on Angulars Router and not based on actual files. Therefore, your configuration can't resolve the routes like `/route`. Besides your assets, you have to redirect/rewrite all requests to your `index.html` in order to handle these by your Angular routing.

```yaml
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
  - (?!^dist)

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(js|css|svg|png)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)
  - url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/.*
```

Please adapt the regular expression if you've got more files you're serving.

Answer (score 0):

Update your flask server so that "/" and "/route" both return your angular index.html. This way angular will handle the routing to display the right content when it's returned by GAE/flask.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why 404 Not Found is showing on page refresh is that all Angular2 routes should be served via the index.html file.

You can fix this issue by adding a **.htaccess** file (in the same directory where the index.html resides) with the following contents.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Didn't do it. Seems as .htaccess files are ignored by Google App Engine. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224764/does-google-app-engine-recognize-and-use-a-htaccess-file