# GCloud Error: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I followed this steps to deploy my angular 8 application in Google Cloud
https://medium.com/@karthiksagar/how-to-deploy-angular-8-app-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp-cdd79e5cc5cf

My app.yaml is as follows

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: sofbox-angular/index.html
    upload: sofbox-angular/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: sofbox-angular
```

I have placed the app.yaml file inside dist/ directory as mentioned.

I am able to access the main url- http://www.myridemate.com/

but when clicked on blog the link is not accessible - http://www.myridemate.com/blog

It gives below error

> Error: Not Found The requested URL /blog was not found on this server.

Tried adding extra handler for /blog in app.yaml and it didn't work.

This same code is working in my local and also in hostgator - https://www.myridemate.alexvijayraj.com/blog

Not sure what I am missing here. Is there some extra configuration required in app.yaml or anything in GCP?

Error Message in App Engine Logs:

```
{
   "time": "2020-09-17T03:58:28.682252Z",
   "severity": "WARNING",
   "logMessage": "Static file referenced by handler not found: sofbox-angular/blog"
}
```

Comment: "Error: Not Found The requested URL /blog was not found on this server." is a Front End error message. Can you please check the Logs of the App Engine version and provide the error in the logs? This will be more informative and helpful to guide you on what may be happening.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for looking into this.. I have posted the message from logs above. Please let me know if you need any other specific information from the log

Comment: The error is kinda clear. You are attempting to make requests to a URL, /blog which is not handled in the App.yaml handlers. The [App.yaml handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) are meant to describe how requests to certain URL patterns are handled.  In the details provided about your App.yaml, you are handling requests to the root URL "/" but you are not handling requests to "/blog" or any other URL "/*". I wonder if you are doing so from within your application code?

Comment: Yes.. It is handled from within the application code. I guess thats how its working with Hostgator. There is no separate route to the "blog" page after I do the production build. I tried adding "/blog" handler but not sure where to point it to.

Comment: Well, if so, then you should perhaps update this thread on how the "/blog" is handled in your application

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this thread worked for me. [Angular 6 routes not found on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315936/angular-6-routes-not-found-on-google-app-engine)

Remember to remove the two handlers that are already on the .yaml file (-url: ...)

```
handlers:
    - url: /(.*\.(js|css|svg|png)(|\.map))$
      static_files: dist/\1
      upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)
    - url: /.*
      static_files: dist/index.html
      upload: dist/.*
```